# How can I make this loop?

Tags: r, matrix, sum

I have a matrix that it contains monthly returns and I want to make a new one in R, that will contain the quarter returns based on this matrix. How can I make a loop to calculate it? To be more precise the matrix of monthly returns has dimensions 552(rows)x25(columns), the new one will have 184(rows)x25(columns), where

- `new(1,1)=old(1,1)+old(2,1)+old(3,1)`
- `new(2,1)=old(4,1)+old(5,1)+old(6,1)`
- ...
- `new(184,25)=old(550,25)+old(551,25)+old(552,25)`

(by the term new(,) I refer to the element of the new matrix and as old(,) of the matrix with the monthly returns). I do not know how to fix this new matrix. Does anybody know how to calculate this in R?

Comment: `for (j in 1:25) { for (i in 1:184) { new[i,j] = old[i*3 -2,j] + old[i*3-1,j] + old[i*3,j] } }` ?

Comment: what does * mean?

Comment: * means multiplication

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try the following code

```
new <- rowsum(old,ceiling(seq(nrow(old))/3))
```

or

```
new <- unname(t(as.matrix(sapply(split(as.data.frame(old),ceiling(seq(nrow(old))/3)),colSums))))
```